# Loading contour file in ds9

Tags: data-analysis, ds9

I have an ASCII file (.con) with the coordinates of vertices of different contours. This file is obtained from Matlab. Now after every set of contour ends there needs to be a blank row in the contour file. In place of this, I have a row with Nan Nan in it when Matlab writes the file. What I do is simply find and Replace the Nan with nothing. But when I load the contour file in ds9 it gives me weird contours. I'm also posting the result I expect (fig 1) and the result I'm getting (fig 2). The problem here that I've understood till now is that if I copy and paste every contour block of coordinates separately into the .con file the result is as expected but I want the whole process of writing the contours from Matlab into the file such that it gives me the expected result in ds9 to be automated (basically I don't want to copy and paste every block). Can somebody help with this?

This is what I expect:

[image: This is what I expect]

[image: This is what I get]

Link for the .con file that gives the right result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDMXtmywJnSjpi_CzCI5-F85oFpebnl4

Link for the .con file that gives the wrong result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18rgN1UVtvcyfJSuh1mmbqOVQCna_aAUM/view

Comment: Can you share a small sample .con file before and after you edit it?

Comment: You mean the one which gives the right result and the one which does not? or before and after I delete the NaNs?

Comment: yes, it does not need to be the whole file, two blocks would be enough. (my suspicion is that it might be related to spaces, tabs or something like that)

Comment: I've added the files. To me, there does not seem to be any space tab difference between the two

Comment: There is indeed a difference with tabs: in conto.con the empty line consist of `linebreak`+`tab`+`linebreak`, in contop.con it is `linebreak`+`linebreak`.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry didn't notice that. All that just because of a tab. Thank you, problem solved

Comment: Good to hear that your problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as pointed out by samcarter in the above comment was to remove the tab in conto.con so that it had linebreak + linebreak instead of linebreak + tab + linebreak